# spring-boot-maven-plugin : Is it possible to resolve dependency from Eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-boot, m2e, spring-boot-maven-plugin

When run projects from Eclipse with m2e plugin, it could resolve dependencies from Eclipse workspace first. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34725991/1568658

When running `mvn spring-boot:run` from command line, it only searches for projects from maven repository. Which means I have to install the dependencies to maven repository via `mvn install` first.

**The questions is:**

- Is it possible to resolve dependencies from Eclipse workspace when running `mvn spring-boot:run` from command line, before searching maven repository.
  This might looks like an unreasonable request, but it could save a lot time, if it's doable.

Comment: Why not using the devtools installed and you can run via `mvn spring-boot:run`...and if you change then something in Eclipse the service will be reloaded immediately...(there is a configuration for that to reduce the amount of time)...

Comment: @khmarbaise If start the spring-boot application from Eclipse directly, then it could find the dependencies from Eclipse workspace, in that case, it's ok. The issue described in the question is in the case to start spring-boot application out of Eclipse, e.g in vi, execute `mvn spring-boot:run`, in this case, I am wondering is it possible that it still could find dependencies from the Eclipse workspace. BTW, not sure which devtools you mean mentioned above.

Comment: Which dependencies from Eclipse workspace ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Say there are 2 maven projects in Eclipse named A and B, B is depends on project A, you can refer to the link mentioned in the question.